# Order by query of columns that are not null in a database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do a sql query ( using Entity Framework or Linq )
And that's the details:

I have an **ApplicationUser** entity, and its important properties are:

> Money

And I also have **Room** entity, which has:

> EnterPrice : Int
>
> Chair0 : ApplicationUser
>
> Chair1 : ApplicationUser
>
> Chair2 : ApplicationUser
>
> Chair3 : ApplicationUser
>
> Chair4 : ApplicationUser

Now I'm trying to write a bit complicated query, and I managed to split it logically to 3 parts:

**Part 1)**

All the results that The CurrentUser has enough money to EnterPrice, and this is the easy part as I did here:

```
var result = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.EnterPrice < user.Chips)
```

**Part 2)**

but now, I want to sort by Chairs that are not null ( by their count ), so for example If I have these Rooms:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Room Name | EnterPrice |    Chair0    |    Chair1    |    Chair2    |    Chair3    | Chair4 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|   Room1   |    10000   |     NULL     | *SomeUserID* |     NULL     | *SomeUserID* |  NULL  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|   Room2   |    8000    | *SomeUserID* | *SomeUserID* | *SomeUserID* |     NULL     |  NULL  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|   Room3   |    12000   |     NULL     | *SomeUserID* |     NULL     |     NULL     |  NULL  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|   Room4   |    13000   | *SomeUserID* |     NULL     | *SomeUserID* | *SomeUserID* |  NULL  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

So the result should be (ascent):

```
Room2
Room4
Room1
Room3
```

Note: And also the following restriction: not showing rooms that are full, so in that case full means all Chairs are occupied.

Now I tried to program this part of the query, and I thought about something like that:

```
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Chair0 != null);
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Chair1 != null);
..

and so on
```

but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do that, and also I don't know how to remove full rooms from the query.

**Part 3)**

And then, a Secondary sorting will be by the average **EnterPrice**, so for example Room2 and Room4 have the same Players count, so the 2nd sort will choose Room4 since it's closer to the average EnterPrice which is:

(10000 + 8000 + 12000 + 13000) / 4 = 10750

It will choose Room4 since:

Room4 : |10750 - 13000| = 2250
Room2 : |10750 - 8000| = 2750

So Room4 is closer to the avg.

Now I have no clue how even to start writing Part 3 of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the Chairs aren't represented by a collection - it would certainly make the query easier/less verbose!

In your part 2, you could consider taking a count of null chairs per-room as part of a temporary projection that you can use in part 3:

```
var part1 = b.Rooms.Where(x => x.EnterPrice < user.Chips);
// define a helper Func that computes a room's count of null chairs
Func<Room, int> NullChairCount = (room) => {
            return 5 
                     - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair0 != null)
                     - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair1 != null) 
                     - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair2 != null)
                     - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair3 != null)
                     - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair4 != null);
          };

var part2 = part1
                 .Select(room => new { 
                                         Room = room, 
                                         NullCount = 5 
                                                  - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair0 != null)
                                                  - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair1 != null) 
                                                  - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair2 != null)
                                                  - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair3 != null)
                                                  - Convert.ToInt32(room.Chair4 != null) 
                                      })
                 .Where(x => x.NullCount > 0) 
                 .OrderBy(x => x.NullCount); // Only rooms that aren't full
// note: you'll want to have some guard logic to handle the case where all rooms are full
var avgPrice = part2.Sum(x => x.EnterPrice) / part2.Count(); // 
// warning: the above may trigger query materialization!
```

From here, you can more easily implement your room choosing algorithm:

```
var closestVal = part2.Min(x => Math.Abs(avgPrice - x.EnterPrice));
var roomChoice = part2.First(x => x.EnterPrice == closestVal); // assumes there is an answer
```

There is of course much room for refinements and improvements in the above; I've focused on clarity and brevity. The key is that you can swap out the implementation of `NullChairCount` if and when your data model changes, since it's the core data model projection that enables the rest of the query logic to work.

Comment: I realized that the logic above computes the average `EnterPrice` using the subset of rooms that are not full -- if you would like to consider all rooms, then simply change `part2` to `part1` in the `.Sum(...)` expression

Comment: Thanks a lot! amazing answer.

Comment: upon further reflection, I realized that the ugly-looking set of ternary statements might be cleaned up a bit by instead casting the boolean result to an int. Editing now (I can't help myself!) :)

Comment: it seems like it's not working, and using the NullChairCount causes this error: System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Comment: okay, you can either a) materialize the query with `.ToList()` (not the best option) or you can replace the `NullChairCount` invocation with the body of the `Func`. makes it less readable, but /shrug that's how it goes sometimes

Comment: Worked! tho need to be changed back to (room.Chair0 != null ? 1 : 0) instead of Convert.ToInt32. thanks!